# Upgrading to Magento 2.0.5 gives Class 'cms/block' not found

Tags: magento2

I just upgraded to 2.0.5 and get the following error in apache log.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'cms/block' not found in
>   /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on
>   line 97

Comment: after migrare you have to just run command php bin/magento setup:upgrade to setup your existing module

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have custom modules or themes or widget that refer to old M1 block name. Remove it and error will gone